# Spring boot: Will a library get dependency from the parent app/service

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

I am using spring-retry in my spring-boot service, as well as spring-boot library.

I Noticed this scenario to work:

1. Use spring retry logic in the library, but the spring retry jars are not imported in the library
2. Use the library in the parent service as a maven dependency.
3. The parent service imports spring-retry maven jars.

Is is normal for the library code to use the maven jars from the parent app ? and not need to import the jars itself ? My common intuition says it should, as the resulting compilation unit will have the dependencies injected.. but not sure.

Sorry if this is a super naive question, but my searches did not give a good answer (maybe want using the right keywords)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I've got you right, probably this question should be rephrased.

So you say, that there is a "spring-boot library" that uses spring retry logic.
If so, this library has a maven module and it gets compiled into a regular jar, right?

But if so, if it uses classes/interfaces/annotations from spring retry library and doesn't have it on the compile class path how it gets compiled? I believe you do have this spring retry library in the dependencies but just don't notice (try `mvn dependency:tree` in the spring boot library module to see the dependencies)

Other than that - usually when you develop a library its intended to be reused by different applications, and if it has dependencies on its own, usually it should list them in the project's library pom. Also usually people who develop the library try to minimize the dependencies list of the library itself.

So if pom.xml of the library doesn't list the required dependencies it won't even compile.

Now in runtime, all the dependencies (including transitive of course) should be available to the spring boot application, otherwise the class that uses these dependencies might not load. But other than that, spring, being a runtime framework, doesn't really care how did the dependency find its way into `BOOT-INF/lib` folder - its expected to work as long as the dependency is there.